# Efficient conversion to PDF using libreoffice with a running instance

Tags: pdf, docx, libreoffice

It seems like unoconv, the command line utility of libreoffice is broken, it can't seem to find the libreoffice installation in latest version.

I'm trying to see what would be an efficient way to do that from the CLI.

Starting an office listener with:

```
soffice "--accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2083;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager"
```

I can see a process running. I now want to be able to simply send the conversion request to that port, such there will be no need to re-open and close the soffice instance.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

I ran this on Fedora release 29

`soffice "--accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2083;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager"`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>This is heading 1</h1>
<h2>This is heading 2</h2>
<h3>This is heading 3</h3>
<h4>This is heading 4</h4>
<h5>This is heading 5</h5>
<h6>This is heading 6</h6>
</body>
</html>
```

`unoconv --connection 'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2220,tcpNoDelay=1;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext' -f pdf test.html`

The command worked fine on both a html files and a **docx** file.

The only time I had a problem was when I tried to run the conversion with LibreOffice open.